# How create ActionBar Menu as in PhotoShop Touch app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The Android PhotoShop Touch app features a custom menu layout launched by tapping an icon on the `ActionBar`. The menu looks like so:

[image]

How did Adobe implement this menu?

I've tried:

- a custom Action Item layout but the layout stays within the `ActionBar's` borders.
- launching an xml menu from the `ActionBar` but it appears *below* the `ActionBar`.

Perhaps the PhotoShop menu is a combination of the two but how does it then align the right side of the menu with the button in all layout configurations?

*Clarification for the Bounty*: I'm wondering:

- how to create a custom layout for a menu launched from a button/item in the `ActionBar`.
- how the button in selected state and the menu can be right aligned, i.e. how to align them along this imaginary red line (so button and menu look like one surface):

[image]

I'm not looking for a complete `ActionBar` solution, but how to do it for one button as an example.

Comment: Maybe a custom [`ActionProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#CreatingActionProvider) or maybe it's even no `ActionBar` at all. You can write your own custom thing, like [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) does.

Comment: @zapl. Thanks. I'll have a look at the ActionProvider link. Re writing  own, I'd prefer to use the existing ActionBar API.

Comment: The bar in the picture does not look a lot like the default actionbar so I guess they did implement something completely custom. But you can do similar things with `ActionProvider` and [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Comment: I already Implement this action bar as a menu. But that is very heavy code. So I can't post that code here.

Comment: @Android Boy. Too bad. Is it an app I can download from the market and have a look at?

Comment: I can show u the picure of that app. Please make sure about that it is your requirement or not...!!!

Comment: Is this your Requirement? This menu is present when touch on File Button.
![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uloXn.png)

Comment: @Android Boy. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately not what I was trying to do. See the update to my post: Trying to make the selected button and the menu aligned so they look like one surface.

Comment: you can align the menu from xml.

Comment: You should implement your own "ActionBar" for this result. The bar itself is a fragment and the "popup"-view is a seperate fragment. This result can not be achieved by using ActionBar or ActionBarsherlock

Answer (score 2):

if you want to stick as close as possible to a code that does not use any special library, without spendings days, you can use a subclass of Spinner :
*res/menu/options.xml :*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/option_spinner"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/myspinner"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

*/res/layout/myspinner.xml :*

```
<com.your.MySpinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

*/src/com/your/MySpinner.java*

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {
    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

and customize that spinner the way you want (replacing its list by your own component based on a GridView, aligning it the way you want, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid), it allows to create floating windows from menu options in the action bar. [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) may also be close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Read :* **Adding an Action Provider .**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider

I think in the picture Up Like in **Action Provider** In Gallery When You Click '**Share**' And The Deference is Just replace them Items layout with your menu I don't know exactly if you can set GridView or any custom layout .. if can , this is what you want .. I didn't try it yet .

OR ..

**See : this sample** [popup window] : http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

I hope This Help .